# BulkSend emails with respective attachments in Gmail using appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api, bulk-email

I would like to send bulk google mails with attachments using a spreadsheet. In this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PBZQww4riYg1oSvUhJ1F4tSK20DHLQCJM_9c5ohTkuM/edit#gid=0), i have put the email address, the content template, and the respective attachment urls.

While i try and execute the below code, everything went well except for the **line item #21 "attachments.push(file.getAs(MimeType.PDF));"**, which shows up an error. While i remove the line#21 and execute, i can send the bulk emails with a HTML Attachment instead of a PDF which contains virus and it is marked as spam.

Can someone help me with the correct code to execute the same and send a pdf directly instead of HTML

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
function sendEmails() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;  
var numRows = 3; 
var blobs = [];

var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)

var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[2]; 
var subject = "Attachments";       
var message = row[4];       
var options = {muteHttpExceptions:true};
var attachments = UrlFetchApp.fetch(row[3], options).getBlob();     
attachments.push(file.getAs(MimeType.PDF));
var emailSent = row[0];     
if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments: attachments,});
  
  sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 1).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
 
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, I thought that the reason of your issue at `attachments.push(file.getAs(MimeType.PDF))` is due to `var attachments = UrlFetchApp.fetch(row[3], options).getBlob();`. At this line, `attachments` is the HTTPResponse object. For this, your script of `attachments.push(file.getAs(MimeType.PDF))` try to put `file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)` to `attachments`. By this, the error occurs. And, `file` is not declared.
- And, when I saw your Spreadsheet, I noticed that the URL of the file is the link of the publicly shared file like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/###/view?usp=sharing`. From this situation, I thought that those files might be publicly shared or your files. If my understanding is correct, I thought that you might be able to be directly retrieved the file using [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive) of `DriveApp` and the method [getBlob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getblob). Furthermore, as you can see in [GmailApp: sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options), the `attachments` parameter inside of the `option` parameter works with `BlobSource` variables, the same that returns `getBlob`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = 3;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[2];
    var subject = "Attachments";
    var message = row[4];
    var fileId = row[3].split("/")[5];
    var emailSent = row[0];
    try {
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
      if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {
        GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, { attachments: [file.getBlob()] });
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 1).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        // SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // I think that this might not be required to be used.
      }
    } catch(e) {
      console.log("File of " + row[3] + "cannot be retrieved. Error message is " + e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In above script, when the file of URL (`row[3]`) cannot be retrieved, that URL can be seen at the log.

#### Reference:

- [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive)
- [DriveApp: Files: getBlob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getblob)
- [GmailApp: sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

Comment: Thank you for your response, i tried running the code and i am able to send the PDFs, but the problem here, Mail 1 has Number.1 attachment, Mail 2 has Number.1 and Number.2 attachments and mail 3 has Number.1, Number.2 and Number.3 attachments. While ideally mail 1 should have 1 attachment and Mail 2 should have Number.2 attachment and follows. Could you please help me with the same

Comment: @Neethu Singuluri Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I understood that you want to send an email by attaching the file of each row. By this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your replying, I apologize again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support and time. I am able to execute the code with Zero errors. This is really helpful for me. Thank you again :) :)

Comment: @Neethu Singuluri Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.